# Select rows in Pandas which does not contain a specific character

Tags: python, pandas

I need something similar to

```
.str.startswith() 
.str.endswith()
```

but for the middle part of a string.

For example, given the following pd.DataFrame

```
      str_name
   0    aaabaa
   1    aabbcb
   2    baabba
   3    aacbba
   4    baccaa
   5    ababaa
```

I need to throw rows 1, 3 and 4 which contain (at least one) letter 'c'.
The position of the specific letter ('c') is not known.
The task is to remove all rows which do contain at least one specific letter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want `df['string_column'].str.contains('c')`

```
>>> df
  str_name
0   aaabaa
1   aabbcb
2   baabba
3   aacbba
4   baccaa
5   ababaa
>>> df['str_name'].str.contains('c')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: str_name, dtype: bool
```

Now, you can "delete" like this

```
>>> df = df[~df['str_name'].str.contains('c')]
>>> df
  str_name
0   aaabaa
2   baabba
5   ababaa
>>>
```

Edited to add:

If you only want to check the first `k` characters, you can `slice`. Suppose `k=3`:

```
>>> df.str_name.str.slice(0,3)
0    aaa
1    aab
2    baa
3    aac
4    bac
5    aba
Name: str_name, dtype: object
>>> df.str_name.str.slice(0,3).str.contains('c')
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: str_name, dtype: bool
```

Note, `Series.str.slice` does not behave like a typical Python slice.

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to check if only first k-letters in 'str_name' contain ''c'?

Comment: So the "~" means inverse?  I'll have to try that out - learned something new.  
df = df[~df['str_name'].str.contains('c')]

Comment: @ArthurD.Howland `~` is vectorized logical negation, so the equivalent of `not`, the same way `and` corresponds to `&` and `or` corresponds to `|`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `numpy`

```
df[np.core.chararray.find(df.str_name.values.astype(str), 'c') < 0]

  str_name
0   aaabaa
2   baabba
5   ababaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use str.contains()

```
str_name = pd.Series(['aaabaa', 'aabbcb', 'baabba', 'aacbba',  'baccaa','ababaa'])
str_name.str.contains('c')
```

This will return the boolean

The following will return the inverse of the above

```
~str_name.str.contains('c')
```